# Getting content of a local file without uploading

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-chrome, file-upload, offline

I'm writing an offline webapp that allows user to select local file, modify it and than saves a copy also locally. Is it possible without any server (I can upload a file and return base64 of it, but it's not much of a offline)? App needs to work only on Google Chrome, so maybe I should look here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML5 File API might prove usefull

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: This specification currently allows files only in the user sandbox. :(

Comment: HTML5 is the future! Use this for future development

Answer (score 2):

```
 input = document.getElementById(inputId);          

 var reader = new FileReader();

 reader.onload = function (e) {
     base64 = e.target.result;
 };

 reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

where input is an element `<input type='file'></input>`. Also works for an input that can select multiple files.

Answer (score -1):

To work with files in the browser I use [downloadify](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify). In order to make it work with paths containing "file://" you need to allow for downloadify.swf access to the file system on the [settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html).

Comment: I guess that you're downvoted because the OP stated "without any server", and someone saw `file://` in your answer. Here, have a +1 for 0.

Comment: There is no server. "file://" appeared here because of Adobe security policy. SWF-file is compiled for the network or to work with the local file system. The downloadify.swf is compiled to work with the network, so there is limited access to the file system.

Comment: @RobW I clearly down-voted him for using flash..