# Browse button to select directory

Tags: java, applet

I want to create a browse button in my web page to select directory and not file. I know that input type file won't work here but is there any way to do it with Javascript. I want to get the filepath of client machine which is possible in IE but other browser are not supporting but that is fine for me.

The way I got stuck is how to get file directory in button.

Below is the code I am using to call applet from browser but I am getting Detected from bootclasspath: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7\lib\deploy.jar error in browser. I have compiled class file using Java 1.5

```html
<applet code="com.life.draw.BrowsePage.class"></applet>
```

### Code

```
public class BrowsePage extends JApplet {
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Browse the folder to process");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "+ chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
        System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "+ chooser.getSelectedFile());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Selection ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is not possible - the only control which has access to the client machine is the `file` input, and that can only select a file, not a folder. Why do you need this?

Comment: Duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page

Comment: webkitdirectory attribute and other modern browsers equivalents `<input type="file" webkitdirectory>`

Comment: Closers: This is **NOT** a duplicate of the "Directory chooser in HTML page" question.  That question has answers that are 3 years old, and are no longer correct.  The answer provided by @Spikeh in _this_ thread is most accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the hell are you calling this in the your `paint` method?  This is likely trying creating to create new windows EVERY TIME the applet is `painted`.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    /*...*/
```

Instead, create a `JButton` in your `init` method and attach an `ActionListener` to it...

```
public void init() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    JButton browse = new JButton("...");
    browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
            chooser.setDialogTitle("Browse the folder to process");
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

            if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "+ chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
                System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "+ chooser.getSelectedFile());
            } else {
                System.out.println("No Selection ");
            }
        }
    });
    add(browse);
}
```

You might also like to take a look at [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)

Comment: problem is not resolved and still window is not getting close even after putting the code in init method. And also there is a small change in my jsp code `<jsp:plugin type="applet" archive="SMyApplet.jar" code="com.life.draw.BrowseDirectory.class" codebase="http://189.28.156.110:8080/imageflow/" jreversion="1.6" width="600" height="320" >. 
    <jsp:fallback>
        Plugin tag OBJECT or EMBED not supported by browser.
    </jsp:fallback>
</jsp:plugin>` Please advice

Comment: It is working now after putting the code in init, actually I changed the code created a jar as well as signed jar but forgot to replace the signed jar after changing the code. Thank You very much my problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can get a local browse dialogue in a web browser is either by using `<input type="file"/>`, or by using a Java Applet or Adobe Flash plugin. There is no built in way to get a directory reference from JS in a web browser.

Also, you cannot read the contents of a client's hard disk, or even initiate a browse dialogue via JavaScript. If you were able to, it would impose considerable security issues.

In reference to reading a directory, take a look at the following posts:

[Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

[Getting content of a local file without uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072294/getting-content-of-a-local-file-without-uploading)

[Javascript: Getting the contents of a local server-side file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123323/javascript-getting-the-contents-of-a-local-server-side-file)

By the sound of it, you're going to need to write a flash plugin that lets you select a directory locally. Your users will be given a security warning when downloading the plugin, though.

Edit:

There's also the webkit based method, but this will only work in webkit based browsers (Chrome, Safari etc).

[How do I use Google Chrome 11's Upload Folder feature in my own code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826286/how-do-i-use-google-chrome-11s-upload-folder-feature-in-my-own-code)

Comment: @RayNicholus I am getting Detected from bootclasspath: C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7\lib\deploy.jar error in browser while runing applet. I have compiled my applet class using Java 1.5. I am adding my JSP and class code above.

Comment: Can someone please tell me what is wrong. when I hit the jsp from server I got classnotfound exception. But if I run in client machine I got error click details with red mark (C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7\lib\deploy.jar)

Comment: ok, I got the solution how to display JFileChooser in applet. Create your own appletpermission.policy make the yourApplet.jar signed and in your code point your code to appletpermission.policy (System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:/C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/security/appletpermission.policy");). For more Information refer [link]http://www.pawlan.com/monica/articles/signedapps/

Comment: But after this I am facing new problem when I click on open or close button I get the value in my code but the JfileChooser window is not closing.